# What VS 2017 RC Installer Individual Components I need for this Scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm a little bit confused with the new Installer in VS 2017, I don't have a really good connection, so I want to only install crucial components that I need, mainly for Unity3d C# text editing and debugging along with simple .Net stuff, Xamarin mobile dev (just compatibility, not the tools themselves) and maybe C++ compiling for UE4 source project.

For now I feel the Workloads are stuffed with unnecessary components like .Net Portable Library TP (1.5 GB), older .Net SDKs and Targeting Packs and database tools etc, all mingling within a confusing inter-dependency that I fear to break.

So my question is what are the Individual Components for a bare minimum C# .Net environment for subsequent Unity and Xamarin development and eventually C++.

I would be very grateful for any elucidations, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One of the goals with the new setup experience in VS2017 is to give you the most streamlined install selections we can fit to your needs.  There are 2 ways that features are grouped:

- **Workloads** give a well-rounded experience in a given topic area, with suggested optional features listed (sometimes are selected by default and some are not; you can always unselect these).  *Workloads are not minimalistic*, they are trying to cover broad development areas and offer a simple set of choices.
- **Individual Components** give you a narrower, more specific feature set.  Each component still keeps track of (and the setup engine enforces) its dependencies; that is, if you install an IC, the functionality of that feature should fully work.  If you try to uninstall an IC, the setup engine will tell you all ICs and Workloads that depend on it, and will prompt to uninstall those as well.  The engine should not let you end up in a broken state (that would be a bug).

If you feel like the Workloads are pulling in too much, feel free to skip them and just jump straight to the Individual Components tab.  Add the features you think you'll need, and their dependencies should get pulled in as well.

Or alternatively, go back into your install, start *un*checking the boxes, and see what the setup engine tells you about dependencies.

From what you've described, the minimum set of components you want will likely be (and some of these may be dependencies of others in the list):

- C# and Visual Basic (under the Development Activities group)
- Visual Studio C++ Core Features (under the Development Activities group)
- Xamarin (under the Development Activities group)
- Visual Studio Tools for Unity (under the Games and Graphics group)

You can always go back and add/remove other options as you feel like it too.

Comment: Does that mean I can ignore the dependency warning without breaking the install?What about .Net

Comment: @JonneyShih you shouldn't ignore the dependency warnings.  Dependencies are required for your features to work (I believe the warning dialog says it will uninstall anything that depends on what you're trying to remove).  But you can get a smaller install by doing it with ICs instead of Workloads.

Comment: As for .NET, you didn't specify which version you wanted to target, so I didn't list it.  Pick the one you want; or, try without and see if the minimum set gets pulled in as a dependency.

Comment: Sorry, my question got cut out, I said can I just install the latest .Net, say version 4.6.2 and ignore other versions especially .Net Portable Library?

Comment: @JonneyShih I believe that is the case.  Unless one of the other features you select has a dependency on Portable Libraries.